# Regexp not matching text on windows, working as expected on a Mac

Tags: java, regex, windows

I have the following code

```
String timeStampSentence = lastedEditedElement.getText();
LOG.info(timeStampSentence);
Pattern timestampPattern =
    Pattern.compile("Last edited by [a-zA-Z]* on ([a-zA-Z]* [0-9]*), ([0-9]*) at ([0-9:]*) ([amp]*)");
Matcher matcher = timestampPattern.matcher(timeStampSentence);
String day = matcher.group(1);
```

The string I'm trying to match ( as output from the LOG ) is `Last edited by admin on January 27, 2017 at 8:12 pm` which, testing online, is [matched](http://fiddle.re/8yj8en)

The exception thrown is ( on Windows, as on Mac it looks like it's working )

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found at
>   java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)   at
>   com.xxx.integration.test.notification.steps.wordpress.editor.WordPressEditorSteps.iShouldBeAbleToSeeTheLastEditedTimestampOnTheEditorPage(WordPressEditorSteps.java:249)
>   at ✽.And I should be able to see the Last edited timestamp on the
>   editor
>   page(F:/content-stack-integration-tests/src/test/resources/features/wordpress/stories-dashboard.feature:24)

jdk is 1.8.0_111 on Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `Matcher#matches()` prior to retrieving the first group:

```
Matcher matcher = timestampPattern.matcher(timeStampSentence);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    String day = matcher.group(1);
    ...
}
```

The documentation of `group()` mentions:

> Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group *during the previous match operation*.

Comment: I agree that we should handle that case, but the problem I have is that the string I have should be matched by the regexp ( and it is matched on Mac and on this site http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html )

Comment: Medified the question to show that I'm logging the string.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti The regex does indeed match the string. But without calling `matcher.matches()`, the `group()` method won't work. The `matches` method is the one that attempts the actual match operation. Did you try adding that call and running your test?

Comment: Ok, you are right, thanks! I hadn't read your answer in full!  :D